# mybatis convert timestamp to java date is wrong

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

mysql 5.7

mybatis 3.4.0

mysql-connector-java-6.0.6

There is a column named `sent_datetime` in a table whose type is `timestamp`:

[image]

there is a record and the value of `sent_datetime` is:

[image]

We can see that its value is `2019-06-20 17:24:34`.

MySql is in a another server whose os is centos 7.

The java bean is(I set the `sent_datetime` as `java.util.Date`):

```java
public class MailLog implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7752106961960847185L;

    private Date sent_datetime; 

    public Date getSent_datetime() {
        return sent_datetime;
    }   

}
```

In `dao`, when I query this record and print the `sent_datetime` value:

```java
MailLog log = mybatisTemplate.selectOne("getMailLog", mailLog);

System.out.println(log.getSent_datetime());
```

However, it prints **Fri Jun 21 06:24:34 CST 2019**. It is wrong.

Meanwhile, if `CST` means American time, it should be **20th**, CANNOT BE **21st**, right?

If I set `sent_datetime` as `String` in java bean, then it prints correct value.

Still, some records save or show incorrect, some are correct.

Why this happens?

In mysql, I run `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone, @@system_time_zone;`, it returns `SYSTEM   SYSTEM    CST`.

Comment: In the tool you see the 20th, in the output the 21st, date run at Centos 27th. I don't know if the latter one is of any value. What makes you sure that the 20th is correct and not modified by a configured timezone?

Comment: The difference from Jun 20 at 17:24 to Jun 21 at 06:24 is 13 hours. A guess could be that CST is for China Standard Time (UTC+08:00) and the query assumes some time zone at UTC-05:00, probably some American time zone, like for example America/Chicago (Central Daylight Time). This would at least explain. Also MySQL might interpret `CST` as North American Central Time (not China Standard Time).

Comment: Would `OffsetDateTime` or maybe `Instant` work for the type of `sent_datetime`? That should at least make the point in time clear on the Java side. Also `Date` is poorly designed and long outdated, there is no reason why you would want to stick to that.

Comment: @teclis Please forget the `date run at centos 27th`, I just want to show the timezone in centos server. I manually insert this record on 20th from Navicat by right click the datetime widget, so I am sure 20th is correct.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for your tip. Another question is, even it is American time, the day in `Date` should be `20th`(that is `Fri Jun 20 06:24:34 CST 2019`) rather than `21st`, right? because china standard time is ahead of american time.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant: the 20th in American time and 21st in Chinese time. @frank

Comment: @OleV.V. I insert this record manually by right click datetime widget from Navicat. And I am sure I am sleeping on `Fri Jun 21 06:24:34 CST 2019`. Therefore I think `20th` is Chinese time.

Comment: Since `CST` is ambiguous a good and easy way to disambiguate the `Date` in Java is `System.out.println(log.getSent_datetime().toInstant());`. This prints the date in UTC. If it prints `2019-06-20T22:24:34Z`, it would at least partly confirm my hypothesis.

Comment: @OleV.V. `System.out.println(log.getSent_datetime().toInstant());` prints `2019-06-20T22:24:34Z`, `System.out.println(log.getSent_datetime());` prints `Fri Jun 21 06:24:34 CST 2019`

Comment: So now we at least know that `Fri Jun 21 06:24:34 CST 2019` is China time. So either the same point in time is in the database or there is a bug in retrieving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of time diff 13h is timezone definition difference between JDBC and MySQL connector.

CST has 2 definitions:

1. Central Standard Time (USA) UTC-05:00
2. China Standard Time UTC+08:00

In this case:

1. JDBC considers timezone is CST-5
2. JBDC transfers Timestamp+0 to CST-5
3. MySQL considers timezone is CST+8，transfer CST-5 to Timestamp-13

For more details, you can reference source code in `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer()` and `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setTimestamp()`

Use `+08:00` instead of `CST` fix this issue.

```
set global time_zone = '+08:00';
```

or

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&autoReconnect=true&serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai
```

Comment: Is there any differences between setting `serverTimezone` in connection url and setting `default-time-zone` in `my.cnf`? Or both are need to be set?

Comment: from source code, serverTimezone priority > default-time-zone. I will post the detail reason in my answer.